# Creating 365 group with Graph API adds "Everyone except external users" to the members site permissions

Tags: development, permissions, graph-api

I am creating a 365 Group using the Graph API version 5.X and when I check the Site Permissions for the Group then I can see a "Everyone except external users" there. I do not want this to be added when I create the Group and I am not sure why or how it is being added.  Does someone know how to not include this permission when creating a Group with Graph API?

I am using the code from this website to create the Group: [Link To Microsoft Example 1 Creating Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-create-a-microsoft-365-group)

[image: OwnersAndMembersGroups]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found my answer.
In the requestBody there is a property called Visibility and a Microsoft 365 group defaults to public. See here: [Group visibility options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#group-visibility-options)
I set mine to "Private" and then the group no longer has that "Everyone except external users" anymore. This makes sense since public groups are exactly that, public, and need to be visible to others so they add this user to the members.